# C++/STL Prime tuples (twin, cousin, sexy) up to the given limit

Tags: c++, primes

As I'm mastering STL I wrote a solution for generating all the prime tuples of the form `(p1,p2)` where "twin" means `p2-p1=2`, "cousin" `p2-p1=4` and "sexy" `p2-p1=6`.

I'm interested in all the comments about the efficiency and style of this solution.

I use the following subroutine from `utilities_template.h` to print vector container:

```
template <class C>
void printContainer(C v, std::string msg = "Container", bool rowWise = true) {
  std::cout << msg << " " << std::endl;
  for (auto it = v.cbegin(); it != v.cend(); ++it)
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << *it << (rowWise ? " " : "\n");
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "utilities_template.h"

enum primeClassification { twin = 2, cousin = 4, sexy = 6 };

void removeElementsInListDivisibleByP(int p, std::list<int>& l) {
  l.remove_if([p](int n) { return n % p == 0; });
}

std::vector<int> getAllPrimesLessN(int n, bool debugMode = false) {
  using namespace std;    
  list<int> l;    
  for (int i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
    l.push_back(i);
  }    
  int min_element = 2;  //    
  vector<int> primes = {min_element};
  while (min_element != l.back()) {
    removeElementsInListDivisibleByP(min_element, l);
    if (debugMode)
      printContainer(
          l, "After divisible by " + std::to_string(min_element) + " removed:");

    min_element = *std::min_element(l.cbegin(), l.cend());
    primes.push_back(min_element);
  }

  auto temp_it =
      adjacent_find(primes.cbegin(), primes.cend(),
                    [](const int& a, const int& b) { return (b - a) == 1; });

  printContainer(primes, "Primes up to " + std::to_string(n));

  return primes;
}

std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > formPrimePairs(primeClassification pClass,
                                                 std::vector<int>& primes) {
  using namespace std;

  std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > pairs;
  for (auto it = next(primes.cbegin(), 1); it != primes.cend(); it++) {
    if (*it - *std::prev(it, 1) == pClass) {
      auto this_pair = make_pair(*prev(it, 1), *it);
      pairs.push_back(this_pair);
    }
  }

  return pairs;
}

void s4PrimePairs() {
  using namespace std;
  int n = 0;
  cout << "Please enter the limit: ";
  cin >> n;

  vector<int> primes = getAllPrimesLessN(n);

  printVectorOfPairs(formPrimePairs(primeClassification::twin, primes),
                     "\nTwin pairs (delta=2): ", true);

  printVectorOfPairs(formPrimePairs(primeClassification::cousin, primes),
                     "\nCousin pairs(delta=4): ", true);

  printVectorOfPairs(formPrimePairs(primeClassification::sexy, primes),
                     "\nSexy pairs(delta=6): ", true);
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: As an aside, while the STL was the inspiration for a big part of the standard library, it was never the standard library, nor a part of the standard library, nor was ever a part of the standard library named that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `std::min_element` is unwarranted. The list is initially sorted, and `remove_if` guarantees to maintain the order of remaining elements. A minimal element is `*l.cbegin()`.
- `removeElementsInListDivisibleByP` is very hard to read. Consider `remove_multiples_of_P`.
- The list initialization loop really wants to be `std::iota`.
- The sieving does work, but it seems less efficient than the classical one.
- If an `std::vector` *can* be used, it performs better than `std::list` (mostly due to preferential locality and less memory overhead). You may want to experiment.
- I don't see what `adjacent_find` is supposed to do. Is it a remnant of some debugging code, perhaps?